# SOLR - DeltaImport

Tags: solr

I'm looking to create a delta import based on if a field is different from last time of index. I unfortunately do not have access to create/modify the schema of the database, so what I have to work with is a field that will always change when a record is updated in the MSSQL database.

i.e. something like:

```
    deltaImportQuery="select * from CatalogItems WHERE ID = '${dataimporter.delta.id}'

deltaQuery="select ID from CatalogItems WHERE indicatorField != '${dataimporter.delta.indicatorField}'
```

I'm using SOLR 6.6.0

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Does each updated row have a distinct value that you have to compare to what the value was in the previous import?

Comment: Yep
it was configured to change in value (is essentially rowversion) each time the row is updated.

Comment: Then I can't see how you'd be able to perform a deltaimport without querying Solr for the existing value, in effect being less effective than performing a reindexing form scratch. Depending on the size of the database, you could implement it on the DB side, but seeing as you don't have access to create or modify the DB, I'm not sure how you'd solve this unless you have a modified time or updated since last import. If you can add tables, you can pull the value at time of update into a secondary table, then join against that to find updated rows when importing.